# Proper syntax for SQL BETWEEN statement with AND clauses

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I'm using the following SQL query in my PHP script:

```
$lng = some lng;
$lat = some lat;
$usertable = $my_db_table;
$interval = 30;
$name = "John Doe";
$query = "SELECT *, POW(69.1*(lat-$lat),2)+POW(69.1*($lng-lng)*COS(lat/57.3),2) AS distance FROM $usertable WHERE obsDt BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL $interval DAY) AND name = '$name' HAVING distance < SQRT(5)";
```

This code works as expected except for the `AND name = '$name'` clause, where it often returns rows with `name` column values other than those equal only to `$comname`. Is there something incorrect in my syntax?

Is there a different way that I should be stating or ordering these clauses?

Comment: Learn to use parameters!  Don't munge query strings with parameter values.

Comment: Thanks, sounds like good practice. How would I do this in my case in PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to finish your BETWEEN clause by specifying the end date:

eg.

```
BETWEEN '2019-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2019-01-02 00:00:00'
```

Comment: Got it, just as @RahulMeshram says, but that's exactly my issue.

Comment: This worked for me: `WHERE name =  '$name' AND obsDt BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL $interval DAY) AND NOW() `

Answer (score 3):

Your query is having some serious problem

```
obsDt BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL $interval DAY) AND name = '$name' HAVING distance < SQRT(5)";
```

In this part, you took `between` clause so between accept two options  like between which two values, you missed that and wrote name = '$name'

Answer (score 2):

```
$lng = some lng;
$lat = some lat;
$usertable = $my_db_table;
$interval = 30;
$name = "John Doe";

$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database;","root","");
$sql="SELECT *,POW(69.1*(lat-:lat),2)+POW(69.1*(:lng-lng)*COS(lat/57.3),2) AS distance";
$sql .=" FROM ".$usertable;
$sql .=" WHERE obsDt < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL :interval DAY)"
$sql .=" AND name = :name HAVING distance < SQRT(5)";

$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
$sth->execute(array(':lat' => $lat, ':lng' => $lng,':name' => $name, ':interval' => $interval));
$res = $sth->fetchAll();
```